# Causal inference in

Tags: r, statistics, inference, causality

This is one of my assignment for causal inference class
The professor wants us to do a simulation, but it is my first time doing it. I am not sure whether this question suits to this community and I am sorry if it does not.

I am currently learning regression discontinuity
Given the code

```
set.seed(1234)
n<-100
x<-runif(n)
y<-pnorm(x,0.5,0.1)+rnorm(n,sd=0.1)
D<-1*(x>=0.5)
```

I really want to understand the code and answer the questions
This is my understanding so far:

- `set.seed(1234)`: try to get the same random number
- `x<-runif(n)`: 100 random number from uniform distribution 0-1
- `y<-pnorm(n,0.5,0.1)+rnorm(n,sd=0.1)`: create a cdf based on 100 random numbers generated and add extra noise..?
- `D<-1*(x<=0.5)`: cutoff 0.5

The professor wants us to

1. Compute the true causal effect which I believe to be E[Y_1i|X]-E[Y_0i|X] = 0.75 - 0.25 = 0.5 since it is a cdf + noise
2. Fit a linear RD model
   Which I can do by

```
cutoff = 0.5
plot(x,y)
abline(v=cutoff, lty =2)

xtilde = x - cutoff
rd <- lm(y ~ D + xtilde + D*xtilde)
xbefore <- seq(0, cutoff - 0.01, 0.01)
ybefore <- predict(rd, newdata = data.frame(xtilde = xbefore - cutoff,
                                            D = 1 * (xbefore >= cutoff)))
points(xbefore, ybefore, type = 'l', col = 'blue', lwd =2)

xafter <- seq(cutoff, 1, 0.01)
yafter <- predict(rd, newdata = data.frame(xtilde = xafter - cutoff,
                                           D = 1 * (xafter >= cutoff)))
points(xafter, yafter, type = 'l', col = 'red', lwd = 2)
```

3. Make a plot of the results above along with E[Y_1i|X]-E[Y_0i|X]

I have no idea what he wants...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As a tip, try to phrase your questions as concisely as possible and make sure your code runs (you were missing the definifion of 'cutoff' in the original version). Regarding your question, you seem to have a good answer already. Perhaps plot the regression on the other part of the data and indicate the size of the discontinuity somehow?